# RecyclerView with SearchView. List will only start to show when typing a text on searchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, searchview

I'm using this recyclerView with searchView app from this [**Github Repository**](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo)

The only changes that I made is instead of getting results from the string array, I am using volley to retrieve data from a web server. I have added a singleton class as well for volley needs it. The only problem that I'm getting is that upon application start, the list won't show up not until I click on the search icon and type some text/characters on it. I'm pretty sure that I'm able to retrieve data from the web server since it will show up upon typing something on the search view. Try to test it guys and please tell me if you're able to resolve it.

On the repo, the MainFragment looks the same as the code below, only adding my codes for fetching data from a server. Take a look at my code:

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }
    private static String url = "http://www.psite7.org/portal/webservices/get_members.php";

    private static final String[] MOVIES = new String[]{
            "The Woman in Black: Angel of Death",
            "20 Once Again",
            "Taken 3",
            "Tevar",
            "I",
            "Blackhat",
            "Spare Parts",
            "The Wedding Ringer",
            "Ex Machina",
            "Mortdecai",
            "Strange Magic",
            "The Boy Next Door",
            "The SpongeBob Movie: Sponge Out of Water",
            "Kingsman: The Secret Service",
            "Boonie Bears: Mystical Winter",
            "Project Almanac",
            "Running Man",
            "Wild Card",
            "It Follows",
            "C'est si bon",
            "Yennai Arindhaal",
            "Shaun the Sheep Movie",
            "Jupiter Ascending",
            "Old Fashioned",
            "Somewhere Only We Know",
            "Fifty Shades of Grey",
            "Dragon Blade",
            "Zhong Kui: Snow Girl and the Dark Crystal",
            "Badlapur",
            "Hot Tub Time Machine 2",
            "McFarland, USA",
            "The Duff",
            "The Second Best Exotic Marigold Hotel",
            "A la mala",
            "Focus",
            "The Lazarus Effect",
            "Chappie",
            "Faults",
            "Road Hard",
            "Unfinished Business",
            "Cinderella",
            "NH10",
            "Run All Night",
            "X+Y",
            "Furious 7",
            "Danny Collins",
            "Do You Believe?",
            "Jalaibee",
            "The Divergent Series: Insurgent",
            "The Gunman",
            "Get Hard",
            "Home"
    };

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ExampleModel> mModels;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mModels = new ArrayList<>();

//        for (String movie : MOVIES) {
//            mModels.add(new ExampleModel(movie));
//        }
        populate();
//        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mModels);
//        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = filter(mModels, query);
        mAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private List<ExampleModel> filter(List<ExampleModel> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ExampleModel model : models) {
            final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }

    public void populate(){
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
//                        hidePDialog();
                        String   email, status;
//                        Member member;
                        final String names[] = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                names[i] = object.getString("firstname") + " " + object.getString("lastname");
                                email = object.getString("email");
                                if(Integer.parseInt(object.getString("activated"))==1){
                                    status = "Active";
                                }else{
                                    status = "Not Active";
                                }
//                                member = new Member(name, email, status);

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
                        for(String name : names){
                            Log.wtf("name", name);
                            mModels.add(new ExampleModel(name));
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                volleyError.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

If you'll notice I just commented the codes that are being used on the repo. I tried to replicate it as much as possible.

Comment: *The only changes that I made...* <= I bet, that's the problem ... but without the actual code it is hard  to say it.

Comment: [First, try learn how to ask before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ... Your question is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*

Comment: Are you the same guy who has contacted me on hangouts by any chance? :-)

Comment: @XaverKapeller yeah it's me lol

Comment: And the problem is simple: You are mixing up synchronous and asynchronous code. What happens in your `Response.Listener` happens long after `populate()` has finished executing. So as I told you yesterday when we first talked about this: The problem is that you don't pass the full list of models to the `Adapeter` when you create it. You pass an empty list and then some time after that you add objects to `mModels` and then when you for the first time filter or do anything which triggers a filter operation then the objects are added to the internal list of the `Adapter` and start to show up.

Comment: Simplest solution: Move the two last lines of `populate()` below the loop where you add the models in your `Response.Listener`. And remove the `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call. **NEVER** use `notifyDataSetChanged()` with a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up synchronous and asynchronous code. If you create and assign the `ExampleAdapter` after you added all models to `mModels` it should work as you expect.

## 1) Fixing your code

```
public void populate() {
    final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    final JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    final String name = object.getString("firstname") + " " + object.getString("lastname");
                    mModels.add(new ExampleModel(name));
                }
                mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mModels);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to parse member json.", e);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

---

## 2) A better Solution

What would be even better is creating the `Adapter` once in `onViewCreated()` and then using the `animateTo()` method whenever your list of models changes:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...
    updateMemberList();
}

public void updateModels() {
    final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    final JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    final String name = object.getString("firstname") + " " + object.getString("lastname");
                    mModels.add(new ExampleModel(name));
                }
                mAdapter.animateTo(mModels);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to parse member json.", e);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Both things work, just what you were trying - which was modifiying the `List` in your `Fragment` - does not. The `Adapter` has its own internal `List` of models and that is the one you need to modify if you want change what is displayed in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Just transferring two lines of codes solved it! Wow, been messing with this for two days. Thank you so much!!